# ngOptions two level object display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-options

I have this structure:

```
model = [
{
  name: 'name1',
  items: [
    {
      name: 'subobj1'
    },
    {
      name: 'subobj2'
    }]
}, 
{
  name: 'name2',
  items: [
    {
      name: 'subobj1'
    },
    {
      name: 'subobj2'
    }]
}, 
    .... 
]
```

Question is: How do I write ngOptions attrbiute to output this object like this?:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="name1">
      <label>subobj1</label>
      <label>subobj2></label>
    </optgroup>
    ....
</group>
```

Also - ngRepeat is not an option. I have to do this ngOptions alone for plugin being used to work.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: The closest I have gotten so far was:
"b.items group by b.name for b in model"
However, it is not iterating over the inner object and only dispalys it as CSV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ngOptions` doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. You must flatten your array first.

Read more in [this answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/-y85myx6Oc0/IhyGGHWBVEEJ).

#### I used a filter:

```
app.filter('flatten' , function(){
  return function(array){
    return array.reduce(function(flatten, group){
      group.items.forEach(function(item){
        flatten.push({ group: group.name , name: item.name})
      })
      return flatten;
    },[]);
  }
})
```

#### And the markup:

```
<select ng-model="select"
        ng-options="item.name 
                    group by item.group 
                    for item in model | flatten"></select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<select>
    <option ng-repeat-start="m in model" ng-bind="m.name"></option>
    <option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="item in m.items" ng-bind="item.name"></option>
</select>
```

You might add something like `style="font-weight: bold;"` on the first option (which is the group label, by the way) and something like `style="padding-left: 15px;"` on the second option line, which is another repeat for all the first option line.
So basically by doing this you just add 2 levels (without `optgroup` tag, mind you) to your select.

Comment: Please explain your answer, especially since you're adding an answer to a question which has had an accepted answer for over a year.