# Angulars: ng-options linked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have this data:

```
{
   "resources":{
      "animals":[
         {
            "id":"1",
            "value":"dog",
            "names":[
               {
                  "id":"1",
                  "value":"Carl"
               },
               {
                  "id":"2",
                  "value":"July"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "id":"2",
            "value":"cat",
            "names":[
               {
                  "id":"1",
                  "value":"Peter"
               },
               {
                  "id":"2",
                  "value":"Frank"
               }
            ]
         },
      ]
   }
}
```

I want a user select: first an animal and then select a name (filtering animal id).
*Getting the ids in the result.*

I thought this example:

```
<select ng-model="select.id_1" ng-options="a.id as a.value for a in resources.animals">
  <option value="">-- choose animal --</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select.id_2" ng-options="...">
  <option value="">-- choose name --</option>
</select>
```

For example(Selection Cat and Frank):

```
select = 
{
    id_1: '2',
    id_2: '2'
}
```

I don't know what code put in the **second ng-options.**

In this example there are two levels, how it would be with **n levels**?

Answer (score 1):

ngOptions doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays.

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="select.id_1" ng-options="a.id as a.value for a in resources.animals" ng-change="firstChange()">
  <option value="">-- choose animal --</option>
</select>

<select ng-model="select.id_2" ng-options="...">
  <option value="">-- choose name --</option>
</select>
```

In JS,

```
$scope.firstChange = function(){
  $scope.Subarray = [];
  for(i=0; i<$scope.resources.animals.length; i++){
    if(select.id_1 == $scope.resources.animals[i].id){
      $scope.Subarray = $scope.resources.animals[i].names;
      break;
    }
  }
 }
```

Use the $scope.Subarray in the second ng options.

Here's a [similar question, maybe try this too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229358/ngoptions-two-level-object-display)